# PHP Multi Array Merging JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got JSON output that comes to me like this

```
{ [objects{}] [to] [from] [total] }
```

and due to the API I'm pulling this from I can only pull 500 records at a time, what I'm trying to do is merge the objects part of multiple json outputs into a larger recordset.

I've tried using array_merge with `json_encode` and `json_decode` but it's not working, I'm assuming it's because of the other arrays (to/from/total) that are impacting my ability to merge.

Any idea how I could go about this, I was thinking of a line by line merge, but issue with this is different types of arrays have different elements (I'm only trying to merge arrays with the same elements).

Edit: hmmm json formatting didn't come through well even with code tags

```php
{
  "objects" : [ {
    "uid" : "f7534a54-fd17-4bc2-9a26-8a567082cc86",
    "name" : "host_10.1.1.1",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "8fe7e918-8530-4a7d-851c-bf8a7c3889c9",
      "name" : "Lab-Ext_VPN",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.1.1.1"
  }, {
    "uid" : "1ba63e41-4d2c-48ea-a970-66a806089ff5",
    "name" : "host_10.1.1.10",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "8fe7e918-8530-4a7d-851c-bf8a7c3889c9",
      "name" : "Lab-Ext_VPN",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.1.1.10"
  }, {
    "uid" : "d798b126-25de-4138-b25d-b1edfe83d259",
    "name" : "host_10.1.1.100",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "8fe7e918-8530-4a7d-851c-bf8a7c3889c9",
      "name" : "Lab-Ext_VPN",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.1.1.100"
  }, {
    "uid" : "247e1b2e-a45d-457e-87f7-78a6acdeea9f",
    "name" : "host_10.1.1.101",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "8fe7e918-8530-4a7d-851c-bf8a7c3889c9",
      "name" : "Lab-Ext_VPN",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.1.1.101"
  }, {
    "uid" : "381e59a0-2094-422a-b538-8f607ec58384",
    "name" : "host_10.1.1.102",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "8fe7e918-8530-4a7d-851c-bf8a7c3889c9",
      "name" : "Lab-Ext_VPN",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.1.1.102"
  } ],
  "from" : 1,
  "to" : 5,
  "total" : 614
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 elements in the given json, `object` `to` `from` and `total`

I am assuming, you hav to merge the `object` from two JSONs, get minimum value of `from`, get maximum value from `to` and sum of `total`

```
function my_merge($json_1,$json_2){
    $array_1 = json_decode($json_1,true);
    $array_2 = json_decode($json_2,true);
    return ['objects'=>array_merge($array_1['objects'],$array_2['objects']),'from'=>min($array_1['from'],$array_2['from']),'to'=>max($array_1['to'],$array_2['to']),'total'=>($array_1['total']+$array_2['total'])];
}
```

Above, first, `json_decode` with second parameter `true` to decode and convert JSON to array.

Second, merge the index `[0]` of both `$array_1` and `$array_2` as it contains the object. Do the `min` `max` and summation for `total` and return the resultant array.

Comment: Still doesn't want to merge the arrays, I'm actually only concerned about the objects array, I've put a sample of the json output in the original post.